# Native Client problem

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to play the game Arcane Legends on Chromium Version 53.0.2785.143 with Ubuntu 14.04. When I click on the game it says the Native Client plugin not installed. My question is how do I install Native Client on Chromium (I guess is where it goes ?) so I can play this game. Thanks in advance

Comment: Acc. to [this](https://chromium.googlesource.com/native_client/src/native_client/+/master/docs/native_client_in_google_chrome.md), try running it like `chromium --enable-nacl --no-sandbox`, and tell if it worked.

Comment: And [acc. to this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1462647) you may need to install [chrome](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome) *(as opposed to lighter chromium)*. If chromium didn't work for you but chrome does, you may want to add yourself to the bug as affected.